# Would it be possible to implement the principals of the K means clustering algorithm in a Neural Network

Tags: neural-networks, clustering, k-means

During a Machine Learning course which I have done I have learnt about the K means algorithm. Is it possible to use the principals of K means within a neural network?

Comment: Do you know what a neural network is? Or are you asking if a neural network can be used to cluster?

Comment: I do know what neural networks are, what I am asking is if you are able to use the principals of K means (the choosing of the cluster centroids and the updating of the centroids position) and use those principals in order to find the optimal centroid position via a neural network.

Comment: Yes it is possible, here is a paper that describes the process: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1808.07292.pdf

Comment: @razvanc92 Feel free to provide a formal answer below. Maybe you could just summarize their abstract or so if you are not familiar with the paper.